# ampliar la imagen para que ocupe toda la cabecera o se repita

Tags: html

Estoy intentado crear una web y su cabecera. He metido una imagen, pero solo ocupa un espacio y quiero que o se repita la imagen o se extienda para ocupar todo. No quiero usar CSS o boostrap o html porque el CSS es mucho lio. Os dejo lo que llevo

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>       
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <title>PHP 3</title>
    <center>
        <img-fluid.max-width:100 src="imagenes/imagenes.jpg" class="img-fluid">
    </center>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">           
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col"></div>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body text-white bg-secondary mb-3">  
                        <h2>Crear cuenta</h2>
                        <div class="form-group">                
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name" required>         
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">                
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter your email" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">                
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Create Password" required>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Crear cuenta</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>                
            <div class="col">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body text-white bg-secondary mb-3">  
                        <h2>Login</h2>
                        <form action="check-login.php" method="post">                               
                            <div class="form-group">                                    
                                <input type="email" class="form-control input-lg" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>        
                            </div>                          
                            <div class="form-group">        
                                <input type="password" class="form-control input-lg" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>       
                            </div>                                  
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Login</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col"></div>
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

prueba a poner el siguiente estilo

```
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: auto;
```